# IntelliCode create own stars

Tags: c#, class, methods, intellisense, intellicode

the stars in IntelliCode show the preferred methods or properties of a class.

Now I want to create such stars for my self-made classes to be able to access my most used methods faster.

How is this possible?

Comment: Its not showing "preferred". VS 2019 got AI for inteli sense. Stars just mark method/properties that AI deducated based on your coding habbits and context of usage.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible, from VS version 16.8 on you are able to train on your current project. This will add stars for your own classes.

view => other windows => intellicode

to enable automatic training on your current project.